# Inbox and reputation changes sometimes don't open in the top-bar

Tags: bug, status-declined

Do only I have this problem sometimes?

[image]

FF 45.0a2 (2016-01-07), Debian testing.

Console output:

> Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox?_=14...05. (Grund: CORS-Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' fehlt).

(translated)

> Cross-origin request blocked: The same-origin rule forbids reading external source https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox?_=14...05. (reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: Is v45 in beta?  Stack Overflow doesn't support beta browsers.

Comment: @psubsee2003, yes it's from FF's aurora channel

Comment: So this is not going to be fixed.  If it is a problem when v45 is officially released, then it is something SE will fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was NoScript, not FF or SO.